# animate header with Angular 5

Tags: css, angular, animation

I am getting to grips with angular animations and I am trying to make a header that will animate properly.
I have been following this tutorial:

https://netbasal.com/reactive-sticky-header-in-angular-12dbffb3f1d3

which is helping me create my header, but I don't want it to do exactly what they are doing, which is why I need some help.
First of all, when scrolling down the page; I don't want the entire header to vanish. Instead I want it to shrink to around 10px; when I scroll back up I would like it to go to 60px;
I have changed the animation to this:

```
trigger('toggle', [
  state(
    VisibilityState.Hidden,
    style({ opacity: 1, height: '10px' })
  ),
  state(
    VisibilityState.Visible,
    style({ opacity: 1, height: '60px' })
  ),
  transition('* => *', animate('200ms ease-in'))
])
```

which works to an extend.
I have some content inside my template that doesn't shrink when the header does.
my CSS for the header component looks like this:

```
:host {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center; // TODO: only for testing, remove later
  background-color: indigo; // TODO: only for testing, remove later
}
```

and the HTML looks like this:

```
<div class="header">
  <p>This is the header</p>
</div>
```

So, the first part of this question, is how do I make the content (whatever it is) hide when the menu is compressed? I am sure that is the easy part :)

The second part to this, is I want to add a new event/animation. When you hover over the menu in it's compressed form, I would like it to expand to it's original size (as if you are scrolling up the page). 
This is hard for me and I would appreciate any help you can give me.

---

*** Update ***

I managed to get the second part to work.
I changed my HTML to this:

```
<div class="header" (mouseenter) ="mouseEnter() "  (mouseleave) ="mouseLeave()">
  <p>This is the header</p>
</div>
```

And added a new property and 2 new methods to the component:

```
private wasVisible = this.isVisible;

mouseEnter() {
  this.wasVisible = this.isVisible === true;
  this.isVisible = true;
}

mouseLeave() {
  this.isVisible = this.wasVisible === true;
}
```

So, when I hover of the component, if it is already visible it will stay that way and when I leave, it will reset to whatever it was like before I entered the component.
If the component was compressed, it will uncompress it and when we move out, it will put it back to being compressed.

Now I just need to figure out how to sort the content.

Comment: How did you conntect the animation to the header? There should be something like `[@toggle]="state"`.

Comment: You can see it in that link I gave; it's part of the component code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so, the only way I could think to do this was to apply a class to the element. So I modified my toggle method to this:

```
@HostBinding('@toggle')
get toggle(): VisibilityState {
  if (this.isVisible) {
    this.renderer.removeClass(this.element.nativeElement, 'collapsed');
  }
  else {
    this.renderer.addClass(this.element.nativeElement, 'collapsed');
  }
  return this.isVisible ? VisibilityState.Visible : VisibilityState.Hidden;
}
```

This allowed me to add modify the CSS of the component like this:

```
:host {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 60px;
    text-align: center; // TODO: only for testing, remove later
    background-color: indigo; // TODO: only for testing, remove later
    .header {
        visibility: visible;
        opacity: 1;
        transition: visibility .2s, opacity .2s linear;
    }
    &.collapsed .header {
        visibility: hidden;
        opacity: 0;
    }
}
```

Now, I am not sure if the CSS will render as smoothly as the Angular animation, but it is the only solution I have found so far.

---

For reference, here is the entire component:

```
import { Component, AfterViewInit, HostBinding, HostListener, ElementRef, Renderer2 } from '@angular/core';
import { animate, state, style, transition, trigger } from '@angular/animations';
import { distinctUntilChanged, filter, map, pairwise, share, throttleTime } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/fromEvent';

enum VisibilityState {
  Visible = 'visible',
  Hidden = 'hidden'
}

enum Direction {
  Up = 'Up',
  Down = 'Down'
}

@Component({
  selector: 'piiick-header',
  templateUrl: './header.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./header.component.scss'],
  animations: [
    trigger('toggle', [
      state(
        VisibilityState.Hidden,
        style({ height: '10px' })
      ),
      state(
        VisibilityState.Visible,
        style("*")
      ),  
      transition('* => *', animate('200ms ease-in'))
    ])
  ]
})
export class HeaderComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  private isVisible = true;
  private wasVisible = this.isVisible;

  constructor(private renderer: Renderer2, private element: ElementRef) { }

  @HostBinding('@toggle')
  get toggle(): VisibilityState {
    if (this.isVisible) {
      this.renderer.removeClass(this.element.nativeElement, 'collapsed');
    }
    else {
      this.renderer.addClass(this.element.nativeElement, 'collapsed');
    }
    return this.isVisible ? VisibilityState.Visible : VisibilityState.Hidden;
  }

  @HostListener('mouseenter')
  mouseEnter() {
    this.wasVisible = this.isVisible === true;
    this.isVisible = true;
  }

  @HostListener('mouseleave')
  mouseLeave() {
    this.isVisible = this.wasVisible === true;
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    const scroll$ = Observable.fromEvent(window, 'scroll').pipe(
      throttleTime(10),
      map(() => window.pageYOffset),
      pairwise(),
      map(([y1, y2]): Direction => (y2 < y1 ? Direction.Up : Direction.Down)),
      distinctUntilChanged(),
      share()
    );

    const scrollUp$ = scroll$.pipe(
      filter(direction => direction === Direction.Up)
    );

    const scrollDown = scroll$.pipe(
      filter(direction => direction === Direction.Down)
    );

    scrollUp$.subscribe(() => (this.isVisible = true));
    scrollDown.subscribe(() => (this.isVisible = false));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Hide content:**

Make the member variable `isVisible` public so you can use it in the view, then hide content with `*ngIf="isVisible"`.

**Hovering:**

Add two methods with `@HostListener("mouseenter")` and `@HostListener("mouseleave")` to the component, implement them like this:

```
@HostListener("mouseenter")
onMouseEnter() {
  this.isVisible = true;
}

@HostListener("mouseleave")
onMouseLeave() {
  this.isVisible = false;
}
```

Comment: Also, should that not be @HostListener?